# The Image in my navigation bar won't display - In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

So i'm trying to do something very simple, display a .png image in the top navigation bar - as the title for the nav bar. The code I've added to viewDidLoad() is:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 18))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "cinevu_name copy.png")
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

If I run this in the simulator, it's absolutely fine. Logo shows perfect. As soon as I run this on a device - its just not there. No errors, just doesn't display. I tried building on an iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s and same issue.

But simulator is fine.

Any thoughts??
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and clean the build folder?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the space in the filename? Can you check that the image is properly loaded on device? E.g. by printing `imageView.image`?

Comment: @Sulthan Just tried that but made no different :( It appears in the simulator but not on my actual device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to make it work with this:

```
// Mark:- Sets image in navigation bar
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME_HERE")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check your constraints. Autolayout will just not put things on the screen sometimes --without giving errors-- if it is confused or ambiguous about where exactly to put it.